# Lottie animation not working correctly

Tags: animation, svg, lottie

I developed this one pager which has Lottie Animation SVG
using the BodyMovin JS Script

Here is a link
http://clients.tipoos.com/scopio

Notice when you get to to the middle part where the title is:
DIAGNOSTIC EXPERTISE IS GEOGRAPHICALLY LIMITED. LET’S SET IT FREE.

You have this animation:
https://prnt.sc/iqoig0

The screen get stucked and the scroll effect is bad in that section
I don't know why it happens
and I can't get any answer anywhere
can anyone assist?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

apparently some containers are not yet in the DOM when you're trying to load the animations. You should make sure the element exists before loading an animation.
For example the element 'coin-mobile' doesn't seem to be present when loading the animation.

Comment: is this the reason why this specific animation doesn't work well? the animation you are talking about are for mobile therefor, they are there but invisible for desktop. is that an issue?
if so why other animations work well on desktop for example the "brain" animaiton? Thanks